# Angular : disable a text input

Tags: angularjs

I have an input text which is disabled by default :

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="city.name" class="form-control"
                                   disabled
                                   name="name">
```

But i want to enable it when the input country is not null :

```
   <input type="text" ng-model="country.name" class="form-control"
                                         >
```

How can i do this in the angular controller ? i start with something like this
in my controller but i dont know how to enable it once the country value is not null

```
  // Watch if the country value is not null
            $scope.$watch("country.name", function (value) {
                if (value !=null) {
                    // enable the city field
                }
            },true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-disabled without going into the controller:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="city.name" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!country.name" name="name">
<input type="text" ng-model="country.name" class="form-control">
```