# How to disable input field for a smart search dropdown in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i am unable to find how to disable or can make a input field  read only for angular js
this is leading into entering any other value which the drop down does not have.

Earlier i have tried with disable property but it is disabling the complete field. Neither input field is enable nor the drop down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular : disable a text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155718/angular-disable-a-text-input)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-disabled` and pass the condition to it .
`ng-disabled="flag"` If the flag is true then the input box will be disabled.